# How to generate Tooltip, Quickinfo or Notification without Mouseover event in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, notifications, tooltip, quickinfo

Is there any possibility in MS Word with VBA to show a short notification message to the user as he begins creating his Word document. I would like to display a short message to him, something like a notification (quickinfo, tooltip but control independent), which displays for about 30 seconds and dissapears automatically, so that the user doesn't have to close the window manually. Similar to the status messages in the system tray, but in Microsoft Word itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom form and set `ControlBox` to false and `FormBorderStyle` to None.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are lots of ways to do this. Some more complex than others. Probably the easiest would be to use a timer with the Application.StatusBar object and then some code like:

```
Sub StatusBarUpdate()
    Application.StatusBar = "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a great idea. But I'm afraid it could be a litte bit to small, I think maybe I need something more eye-catching.